# 絵文字を格納したいが　?????　になる

Tags: java, android, mariadb, jdbc

アプリ　JavaDataInputStream　JDBC-MariaDB　MariaDB
の順で絵文字を格納したいのですが、格納される文字が　?????　になります。（絵文字部分だけ）
全ての絵文字がそうなるわけではなく、サロゲートペアのものがそうなります。
もちろん通常の文字だけなら普通に格納されます。

データベースのテーブルは　utf8mb4　で、カラムも　utf8mb4　であることを確認しています。
useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8mb4　をつけてコネクションを取得しています。

試しに　set names utf8mb4　も試しましたがこれもダメでした。

何をしても　???　で保存されてしまうのですが何処が行けないのでしょうか？

追記
やはり解決できません

□絶対だと分かっていること
・テーブルは正常にutf8mb4である
カラム単位でチェック済み
これをする前は例外が発生していたが、これをしてから例外は発生しなくなった。
そもそも、コネクションを通さなければ格納できる。

・コネクションは1.2.3（mariadb java）
サロゲートペアが？になるバグは修正されているとここでの解答してくださった方により判明

・アプリ　←→　サーバー　の通信はうまく行われている。
DBに格納しないでそのままエコーすると正常に表示される。

・悪いのは　MariaDB　コネクション
ターミナルなどではサロゲートペアでも普通に格納できる。
また、PrepareStatementを使用している点が怪しい？
（？をエスケープして置換してくれるやつ）

・コネクションには以下を指定（うるおぼえ）
useUtf=tru　charset=utf8mb4

・MariaDBにデータが届いた時点で文字化けではなくそもそも　？　という文字に置き換わっていると思われる。
やはり、コネクションでの変換が原因？

要するに悪いのは絶対　MariaDB　Connection Java　だと思われるのですが、とても困っています。

追記追記
対応できました！！！！！！！！！！！！
原因　SQLの関数　ストアドプロシージャ　の　client_character　的なのが　utf-8　だった。

Comment: その絵文字はsurrogate pair(サロゲートペア)に引っかかる文字列だけですか？surrogate pairに引っかからない絵文字もありますが、それはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
引っかかるものだけです。
また、
「絵文字が入った文字列だと絵文字以外の部分も　????　になります。」
は間違いでした修正します。

Comment: Androidだったのですが、???はただの文字化けというか対応している文字がないためのものだったようです。
通知に文字列を表示したら絵文字も通知に表示されました。
ですが、TextViewに表示したら???になってしまいました。
そのため、勘違いをしてしまったのですが、mb4での保存などはうまく言っており、TextViewだけがおかしいということが分かりました。
こちらは解決していませんが、原因が分かって良かったです。

Comment: 嘘言いました
通知はサーバーでデータベースに保存せずに、クライアントから取得したものをGoogleに送信していただけなので、
おかしい部分はデータベースに保存するときか取得するときということになります。

Comment: 対応できたということですが、ぜひ具体的な解決策をご自身で回答として投稿していただければと思います。

Comment: そのようなこともできるのですね
初めてなもので…
了解です。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

自己解決

### 原因

ストアドプロシージャ（関数など）の `client_` が `utf-8` のままだった。
まさか、　ストアドプロシージャ　にも文字コードの設定があるとは気づかず、とてつもない時間を解決に要してしまいました。

ちなみにですが、私の実行できた設定は以下になります。
（やはり設定トラブルも多いようなので）

### 確認方法

```
show create PROCEDURE xxxxxxx;
```

`character_set_client` が `utf-8` だった
また、ほかに続くのも `utf8_general_ci` だった。

---

### /etc/my.cnf（必要な部分のみ）

```
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server=utf8mb4
[mysql]
default_character_set=utf8mb4
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

---

### コネクション

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost/" + D.DataBaseName + "?user=" + D.DataBaseUser + "&password=" + D.DataBasePass + "&autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8mb4&connectionCollation=utf8mb4_general_ci");
```

`set names` などの発行はなし。
`skip-character-set-client-handshake` も使用していない

---

### データベース

テーブルの文字コードは `utf8mb4`
テーブルのカラム単位でも文字コード指定ができるみたいなのでそれも同じく `utf8mb4`

Answer (score 3):

以下は回答ではなく、こちらの環境で試してみた結果です。

**実行環境**

- OS: Ubuntu Linux 15.04
- MariaDB: 10.0.20
- Java: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment(build 1.9.0-ea-b81)
- MariaDB Connector/J: 1.3.0-beta2

以下のサンプルプログラムを実行してみました。MariaDB Connector/J に含まれているサンプルプログラムでは絵文字を `byte[]` にしていますので、それも試しています。

```
PreparedStatement ps =
  connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO emojiTest (id, field) VALUES (?, ?)");

ps.setInt(1, 1);
ps.setString(2, "");
ps.execute();

byte[] emoji = new byte[]{(byte) 0xF0, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x98, (byte) 0x84};
ps.setInt(1, 2);
ps.setBytes(2, emoji);
ps.execute();
```

MariaDB 側で表示してみると、どちらも正常に表示されています。

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from emojiTest;
+------+-------+
| id   | field |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     |
|    2 |     |
+------+-------+
```

これは関係があるのかどうか不明ですが、MariaDB の config ファイルに、`skip-character-set-client-handshake` を追加しています。

```
#
# * Character sets
#
# Default is Latin1, if you need UTF-8 set all this (also in client section)
#
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character_set_server  = utf8mb4
collation_server      = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

`skip-character-set-client-handshake` を指定しないと文字化けを起こしますが、`set names utf8mb4;` を実行すれば良いだけの話ですので、あまり関係はないのかもしれません。

Comment: なるほどですね…
となると、問題はConnectionの文字コードて感じですね

私は
--
[mysqld]
collation_server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-server=utf8mb4
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
[mysql]
default_character_set=utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
--
という設定です。
（skip-character-set-client-handshakeは使ってみたこともありましたがだでした、一応もう一度試してみます。
ですが、なんか、インジェクションの危険があるとか…？）

ちなみに　procedure　をJavaでコールして格納しているのですがこれは関係ないですよね？
sql文は　procedure　をコールして格納する文を発行しています。

Comment: @D.T  ストアドプロシージャでも試してみましたが、正常に insert できています

Comment: 私より先に試していただいてありがとうございます！
本当に謎です。明日ゆっくりと色々実験してみたいと思います！

Answer (score 2):

? になるのはJava側の問題のような気がします。
[こちら](http://qiita.com/PGMY/items/4529494b7205ae0b2672)の記事によると古いJDBCドライバの場合、???? になるそうですのでJDBCドライバのバージョンを変えてみるのはどうでしょう。

Comment: 最新のMariaDBのドライバを使用しています…
とはいえ、おそらくMySQLのドライバをベースに作られているので
MySQLのドライバでは修正されていても修正されていない可能性もありますよね
調べてみます

Comment: MariaDB の JDBC では 1.1.8 で utf8mb のバグが修正されてます。最新を使われてるということであれば私の回答は的外れっぽいですね。 なお参考までに 絵文字のテストケースが GitHub にあるので使い方を参考になさってはどうでしょうか。 https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-j/blob/master/src/test/java/org/mariadb/jdbc/CollationTest.java

Answer (score 2):

Javaでサロゲートペアをサポートしようとするとそれぞれのキャラクタをコードポイントに変換する必要があります。

```
public static int[] toCodePoints(String str) {
    int length = str.codePointCount(0, str.length());
    int[] codePoints = new int[length];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i = str.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1)) {
        codePoints[j++] = str.codePointAt(i);
    }
    return codePoints;
}
```

上記でコードポイントに変換した配列が返ってきますので、区切り文字で区切って格納すればどうでしょうか？
読みだすときは`split`で配列にしてコードポイントから文字列に変換すればいいかと……

```
public static String toString(int[] codePoints) {
    return new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);
}
```

……と、コードポイント変換のコードを添付しましたが、
自分は上位下位に分かれてくれるので普段ライブラリを使って一旦JSON化してます。

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
私の環境では変化なしという感じでした…